# Highlighting an image

Tags: c++, image, multidimensional-array

My instructor wrote 
'One way to highlight objects in an image is to make all pixels below a threshold (T1) 0, and all pixels above a threshold (T2) 255. Write a function to highlight the image, using the following prototype:

```
void highlight(int image[][MAXHEIGHT],int width, int height, int t1, int t2)
```

Write a main program that inputs t1 and t2 from the user, highlights the image, and then writes the image. "

I already have functions that can read and write an image but I have no idea how to change the pixels of an image.

Code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

const int MAXWIDTH = 512;
const int MAXHEIGHT = 512;

// reads a PGM file.
void readImage(int image[][MAXHEIGHT], int &width, int &height) {
  char c;
  int x;
  ifstream instr;
  instr.open("city.pgm");

  cout << "This is running " << endl;

  // read the header P2
  instr >> c;  assert(c == 'P');
  instr >> c;  assert(c == '2');

  // skip the comments (if any)
  while ((instr>>ws).peek() == '#') { instr.ignore(4096, '\n'); }

  instr >> width; 
  instr >> height;

  assert(width <= MAXWIDTH);
  assert(height <= MAXHEIGHT);
  int max;
  instr >> max;
  assert(max == 255);

  for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) 
    for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) 
      instr >> image[col][row];
  instr.close();
  return;
}

// Writes a PGM file
void writeImage(int image[][MAXHEIGHT], int width, int height) {
  ofstream ostr;
  ostr.open("outImage.pgm");
  if (ostr.fail()) {
    cout << "Unable to write file\n";
    exit(1);
  };

  // print the header
  ostr << "P2" << endl;
  // width, height
  ostr << width << ' '; 
  ostr << height << endl;
  ostr << 255 << endl;

  for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
      assert(image[col][row] < 256);
      assert(image[col][row] >= 0);
      ostr << image[col][row] << ' ';
      // lines should be no longer than 70 characters
      if ((col+1)%16 == 0) ostr << endl;
    }
    ostr << endl;
  }
  ostr.close();
  return;
}


int main ()
{
 int image[MAXWIDTH][MAXHEIGHT], width, height, t1, t2;

 readImage (image, width, height);
 writeImage (image, width, height);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your image is just in that array of integers, no? What more is there do to? You just said you have functions for reading and writing.

Comment: Sure that one pixel is represented by an integer value? A char array makes more sense here. However, writing is something like this: `image[width][height] = 0`

Comment: Should I just post the code I have so far? I'm still confused on what to do.

Comment: Couldn't hurt, more insight is always helpful.

Comment: Okay, I added the code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

After all the code you already wrote, including the analysis of the PGM header, I don't understand why you ask for this.

```
void highlight(int image[][MAXHEIGHT],int width, int height, int t1, int t2) {
    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) 
        for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) 
            if (image[col][row]<t1) 
                image[col][row] =0; 
            else if (image[col][row]>t2) 
                image[col][row]=255;
}
```

***Edit:*** I've used your indexing scheme, which seems consitent and should work. Nevertheless, the usual practice is to represent the 2D array so that the row is the first index and the column the second. In this way, a row is represented by consecutive elements.

Comment: Ah, my instructor gave us most of the readImage and writeImage code so we had to add onto it.